# Regex for alphanumeric port range

Tags: regex, perl

My regex is:

```
([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])
```

Please tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: I want to use alphanumeric string with Port (0-65535).

Comment: Perhaps, you are looking for [`\b[a-zA-Z]*(?:[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])\b`](https://regex101.com/r/rE6oO8/2)? Hard to guess without concrete examples.

Comment: Regex only is not optimal solution for this task.

Comment: I want to right down a regex which validates an alphanumeric string and port number.
For e.g : Port123 , 6345, 23, wel24

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Because `perl` can do this way better than a `regex` can.

Answer (score 1):

You regex matches 2 alternatives: 1 lower- or uppercase letter with `[a-zA-Z]`, or a number with `[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]`.

It seems you are looking for

```
\b([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*|(?:[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]))\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rE6oO8/7)

Or, if the strings are tested against the regex individually, use `^`/`$` anchors:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*|(?:[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]))$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/rE6oO8/8)

Comment: It seems good. But it is not taking alphabets. Sorry i missed that part in above examples(Port, Port123,0-65535).

Comment: I added an option for those cases, too.

Comment: If you want to avoid all the digit repetitions, `\b(\d+)(??{$^N<65536?"":"(?!)"})\b` matches a number from 0 to 65535.

Comment: @CalleDybedahl: Thank you for a good hint, I also added that to my answer with some links.

Comment: This is not working in case of "Port70000". Showing it as invalid. It should be valid.

Comment: I am sorry, but `70000` is greater then `65535`. Your requirement was to match port numbers in the `0-65535` range. What is your requirement then?

Comment: "abchdf13443423745" should be valid. If  only digits(\d) then range should be upto 65535.

Comment: @VishnuGodara: Please check now